# how to access elements of array in another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array which contains an array:

```
Array
(
[title] => SwB Skipper
[today] => 08/11/2016
[crew_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Bob S
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Janet 
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => Perry S
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [name] => Vinay N
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [name] => Pace W
            )
```

The array is called `$values;`

I do an:

```
extract($values);
```

and then try to access the `$crew_name['name']` elements with

```
<?php foreach ($crew_name['name'] as $crew): ?>

          <option value = "<?php echo $crew['name']; ?>" > 
          <?php echo $crew['name']; ?> </option>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not ready for the `['name']` key at the top level of `$crew_name`. `$crew_name` only has numeric keys, so you just need

```
<?php foreach ($crew_name as $crew): ?>
```

The rest of it should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $values is the main array Try this:

```
foreach($values as $val){
    foreach($val["crew_name"] as $crew){
        echo $crew["name"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use [aray_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function and make your multi array a compact single dimension one. That would make things a lot simpler.

Try this:

```
<select>
  <?php
      $options = array_column($values["crew_name"], "name");
      foreach($options as $option) {    
   ?>
    <option value = "<?php echo $option; ?>" > 
      <?php echo $option; ?> 
    </option>
   <?php } ?>
</select>
```